# antivirus for sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, anti-virus

I need some style of antivirus for sharepoint, mainly for scanning any uploaded user documents.

Is there anything (cheap) available out there that you have used before?
I contacted our regular anti-malware company and they quoted us at $40,000 for our 4 sharepoint servers..

Comment: Can you define cheap (40k sounds pretty cheap to me) and what vendor(s) you've already contacted about pricing?

Comment: A suitable price range would be below 10K, I've contacted Mcafee about it only so far.
I would like other peoples advice on who would be the best choice to contact next.

Comment: doesn't MS's forefront work with sharepoint? I'm sure it wouldn't be 40k and would actually work unlike mcafee.

Answer (score 4):

[Microsoft Forefront Security for Sharepoint](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/sharepoint/en/us/default.aspx): ~$1200 per Internet-Facing Server

I have to find the per-user SKUs (for Intranet sites), but I know it's $7.20 per user + some amount for the server.

Comment: Sounds nice, I have to contact a supplier but this is per server license or per user? 
The amount of users numbers in the tens of thousands so any user based license isn't feasible.

Comment: You have to contact a provider. Your exact price will depend on the license agreement; unfortunately it's very different for every level.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking, you may want to check out Metascan which is most often used for file upload servers as mentioned... pricing starts well below your stated quote above, and allows for integration of up to 30 antivirus engines (the pricing obviously fluctuates with the number of engines requested).

#### Disclaimer/// I work for OPSWAT who produces Metascan, but it seemed to be a valid option for the question at hand so I wanted to make sure they were aware

Comment: I suppose since it doesn't have an accepted answer it's still available, but this is a year old question.